# Selectize Input style in Shiny (font color of selected items)

Tags: css, r, shiny

so I'm new to CSS and Shiny and I reached to change the colors of the items through testing about their names. As we can see the item Banana will have a font color yellow, Kiwi green and Tomato red.
But now what I wanna do is that I want to keep these font colors when I select the items

```
shinyApp(
 ui = fluidPage(
  tags$head(
   tags$style(HTML("
                 .item {
                  background: #2196f3 !important;
                  color: red !important;
                  }
                  .selectize-dropdown-content .active {
                  background: #2196f5 !important;
                  color: white !important;
                  }
                  .selectize-dropdown [data-value=\"Tomato\"] { 
                  color: red }
                  .selectize-dropdown [data-value=\"Kiwi\"] { 
                  color: green }
                  .selectize-dropdown [data-value=\"Banana\"] { 
                  color: yellow }
                  "))
  ),uiOutput("type")),

server = function(input, output, session) {
output$type <- renderUI({
  selectInput("color", "Color",as.list(fruits),multiple = T)
})
}
)
```

So I tried this

```
.item [data-value=\"Banana\"]{
                  background: #2196f3 !important;
                  color: yellow !important;
                  }
.item [data-value=\"Tomato\"]{
                  background: #2196f3 !important;
                  color: red !important;
                  }
.item [data-value=\"Kiwi\"]{
                  background: #2196f3 !important;
                  color: green !important;
                  }
```

But this isn't working, it still launches the app but it ignores the condition of ***data-value = ...*** , so maybe in ***.item*** we have to deal with another way the condition about which fruit is it.

Thx and have a good day !

**EDIT :** Ok I'm bad ^^ I found the solution we just have to do the same but instead of using ***selectize-dropdown***, we use ***selectize-input*** and we condition through ***data-value = ...*** in it. Like this :

```
.selectize-input[data-value=\"Tomato\"] { 
                  color: red }
.selectize-input[data-value=\"Kiwi\"] { 
                  color: green }
.selectize-input[data-value=\"Banana\"] { 
                  color: yellow !important}
```

Comment: Did you try `.selectize-dropdown [data-value=\"Banana\"] { background:#2196f3; color: yellow !important; }` ?

Comment: This works just in the list, what I want is this just for the font color but after I selected the item from the list

Comment: when I do `tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".item {background-color: #92e09b !important}"))),` that's all I need to change the background/font color.